# Undeclared variables usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does JavaScript throw a reference error if we try use a variable which is not declared but allows to set the value for the same ?

e.g

```
a = 10; //creates global variable a and sets value to 10 even though its undeclared
alert(b); // throws reference error.
```

so why for b, its reference error and not for the a?

Comment: because in case a = 10 it sets the variable, and in case of alert(b) it searches variable and can not find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just how the language works. In non-strict mode, an assignment to an undeclared symbol is implicitly treated as creating a global variable. In strict mode, that's an error.

To use strict mode, a global script block or a function should start with the statement:

```
"use strict";
```

That is, a simple expression statement consisting of the string `"use strict"`. That will prevent the accidental creation of global variables (which can still be created explicitly), and impose a few other restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any
>   code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its
>   current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or,
>   for variables declared outside any function, global.
>
> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a
>   global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the
>   assignment is executed. The differences between declared and
>   undeclared variables are:
>
> 1. Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared. Undeclared variables are always global.
> 2. **Declared variables are created before any code is executed. Undeclared variables do not exist until the code assigning to them is
>      executed.**

```
console.log(a);                // Throws a ReferenceError.
console.log('still going...'); // Never executes.
```

---

```
var a;
console.log(a);                // logs "undefined" or "" depending on browser.
console.log('still going...'); // logs "still going...".
```

> 3. Declared variables are a non-configurable property of their execution context (function or global). Undeclared variables are
>      configurable (e.g. can be deleted).
>
> Because of these three differences, failure to declare variables will
>   very likely lead to unexpected results. Thus it is recommended to
>   always declare variables, regardless of whether they are in a function
>   or global scope. And in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, assigning to an
>   undeclared variable throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

`a = 10;`
 internally declares `var a`
i.e. in background it first declares the variable globally and then set the value for that variable.

So whenever we write 
`a=10`
what actually happens:
`var a;`
`a=10;`
hence `a` is never `undefined`;

but `alert(b)` in this case `b` has no values defined so it remains `undefined`

And as Pointy said,

> In non-strict mode, an assignment to an undeclared symbol is implicitly treated as creating a global variable. In strict mode, that's an error.

Its always a better practice to use `use strict`